# ngx-socket-io connected false but flask_socketio logs show 200 OK

Tags: python-3.x, angularjs, flask-socketio, ngx-socket-io

Any tips to debug would help, this is just the basic implementation.

I am using the exact tutorial as here to setup the ngx socket client:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

flask-socketio        for the server
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Server-side shows no error, but the registered handler methods to emit/receive seem blind.

Server Logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 10:58:51] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NT8Dtbg HTTP/1.1" 200 418 0.000640
(12285) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 37400)
fa1a1d40bbc349c384a121302ef567c7: Received request to upgrade to websocket
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 10:58:51] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NT8Dtcd&sid=fa1a1d40bbc349c384a121302ef567c7 HTTP/1.1" 200 235 0.000408
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 10:58:51] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NT8DtdE&sid=fa1a1d40bbc349c384a121302ef567c7 HTTP/1.1" 200 235 0.000268
fa1a1d40bbc349c384a121302ef567c7: Upgrade to websocket successful
5002732d42184ba6b453e7d4f35e864e: Received packet PING data None
5002732d42184ba6b453e7d4f35e864e: Sending packet PONG data None
```

Client logs:

```
config: {url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", options: {…}}
emptyConfig: {url: "", options: {…}}
eventObservables$: {}
ioSocket: Socket
acks: {}
connected: false
disconnected: true
flags: {}
ids: 0
io: Manager
autoConnect: true
backoff: Backoff {ms: 1000, max: 5000, factor: 2, jitter: 0.5, attempts: 0}
connecting: [Socket]
decoder: Decoder {reconstructor: null, _callbacks: {…}}
encoder: Encoder {}
encoding: false
engine: Socket {secure: false, agent: false, hostname: "127.0.0.1", port: "5000", query: {…}, …}
lastPing: Thu Jan 28 2021 11:00:56
```

Server code (no print)

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print('\n\nClient connected')
```

Why can't I get the connection working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double check npm/python environment of current versions of socketio and engineio.
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio

```
d7e95928d73c42fab431e94ce2df40fc: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'd7e95928d73c42fab431e94ce2df40fc', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}


Client connected
d7e95928d73c42fab431e94ce2df40fc: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
```